# User input to display shortest path

Tags: java, user-input, indexoutofboundsexception, breadth-first-search

I am having an ArrayOutOfBounds exception and I do not know why. I am trying to get the user to input which city they want the program to start at, then have my program perform the breadth first search from that point.

My program is due in an hour so any quick help would be great!

Really quick, my program performs a breadth first search on an adjacency matrix!

Thanks guys, here is my main:

```
       import java.util.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {



        //Lets create nodes 
        Node Seattle = new Node("Seattle");
        Node Vancouver=new Node("Vancouver");
        Node Portland = new Node("Portland");
        Node Houston = new Node("Houston");
        Node New_Orleans = new Node("New_Orleans");
        Node Miami = new Node("Miami");
        Node Omaha = new Node("Omaha");
        Node Louisville=new Node("Louisville");
        Node Boston = new Node("Boston");
        Node Boise = new Node("Boise ");
        Node Chicago = new Node("Chicago");
        Node Jacksonville = new Node("Jacksonville");
        Node Baltimore = new Node("Baltimore");
        Node Detroit = new Node("Detroit");
        Node Nashville =new Node("Nashville ");
        Node Oakland  = new Node("Oakland ");
        Node Denver= new Node("Denver ");
        Node Olympia = new Node("Olympia");
        Node Memphis = new Node("Memphis");

//
        //Create the graph, add nodes, create edges between nodes
        g.addNode(Seattle);
        g.addNode(Vancouver);
        g.addNode(Portland);
        g.addNode(Houston);
        g.addNode(New_Orleans);
        g.addNode(Miami);
        g.addNode(Omaha);
        g.addNode(Louisville);
        g.addNode(Boston);
        g.addNode(Boise);
        g.addNode(Chicago);
        g.addNode(Jacksonville);
        g.addNode(Baltimore);
        g.addNode(Detroit);
        g.addNode(Nashville);
        g.addNode(Oakland);
        g.addNode(Denver);
        g.addNode(Olympia);
        g.addNode(Memphis);

//      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
//      String shortPath = sc.next();
//      Node spath = new Node(shortPath);


        g.connectNode(Louisville,Memphis);

        g.connectNode(Houston,Seattle);

        g.connectNode(Boston,Vancouver);

        g.connectNode(Boise,Seattle);
        g.connectNode(Boise,Detroit);
        g.connectNode(Boise,Oakland);

        g.connectNode(Chicago,Olympia);

        g.connectNode(Portland,Seattle);

        g.connectNode(Jacksonville, Vancouver);

        g.connectNode(Baltimore, Vancouver);

        g.connectNode(Detroit, Boise);

        g.connectNode(Seattle, Portland );
        g.connectNode(Seattle, Houston );
        g.connectNode(Seattle, Vancouver);
        g.connectNode(Seattle, Denver);
        g.connectNode(Seattle, Boise);

        g.connectNode(Nashville, Memphis);

        g.connectNode(Oakland, Boise);
        g.connectNode(Oakland, Vancouver);

        g.connectNode(Vancouver, Seattle);
        g.connectNode(Vancouver,Olympia);
        g.connectNode(Vancouver,Jacksonville);
        g.connectNode(Vancouver,Baltimore);
        g.connectNode(Vancouver,Oakland);
        g.connectNode(Vancouver,Boston);

        g.connectNode(Denver, Seattle);

        g.connectNode(Olympia,Vancouver);
        g.connectNode(Olympia,Omaha);
        g.connectNode(Olympia,Chicago);

        g.connectNode(Memphis,Nashville);
        g.connectNode(Memphis,Louisville);
        g.connectNode(Memphis,Omaha);

        g.setRootNode(Houston);
        //Perform the traversal of the graph
        System.out.println("Shortest path is ------------->");
        g.bfs();
        ;
//      }
//      else {
//          throw new InvalidInputException();
//      }

        long lEndTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
        long difference = lEndTime - lStartTime;
        System.out.println("\nElapsed Time: " + difference + " ms");



    }

}
```

Node class:

```
public class Node 
{   


    public String label;
    public String label2;
    public boolean visited=false;
    //public Object equals;
    public Node(String name)
    {
        this.label= name;
//      this.label2 = name2;
    }
}
```

and my graph class:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.*;


public class Graph 
{
    //added
//  Vertex[] adjLists;

    public Node rootNode;
    public ArrayList nodes=new ArrayList();
    public int[][] adjMatrix;//Edges will be represented as adjacency Matrix
    int size;

    public void setRootNode(Node city)
    {
        this.rootNode=city;
    }

    public Node getRootNode()
    {
        return this.rootNode;
    }

    public void addNode(Node city)
    {
        nodes.add(city);
    }

    //This method will be called to make connect two nodes
    public void connectNode(Node start,Node end)
    {
        if(adjMatrix==null)
        {
            size=nodes.size();
            adjMatrix=new int[size][size];
        }

        int startIndex=nodes.indexOf(start);
        int endIndex=nodes.indexOf(end);
        adjMatrix[startIndex][endIndex]=1;      //initializing matrix with size 1 by 1
        adjMatrix[endIndex][startIndex]=1;
    }

    private Node getUnvisitedChildNode(Node n)
    {

        int index=nodes.indexOf(n);             //index is = to index of nodes
        int j=0;
        while(j<size)
        {
            if(adjMatrix[index][j]==1 && ((Node)nodes.get(j)).visited==false)
            {
                return (Node)nodes.get(j);
            }
            j++;
        }
        return null;
    }

    //BFS traversal of a tree is performed by the bfs() function
    public void bfs()
    {

        //BFS uses Queue data structure
        Queue q=new LinkedList();
        q.add(this.rootNode);
        printNode(this.rootNode);
        rootNode.visited=true;
        while(!q.isEmpty())
        {
            Node n=(Node)q.remove();
            Node child=null;
            while((child=getUnvisitedChildNode(n))!=null)
            {
                child.visited=true;
                printNode(child);
                q.add(child);
            }
        }
        //Clear visited property of nodes
        clearNodes();
    }


    //Utility methods for clearing visited property of node
    private void clearNodes()
    {
        int i=0;
        while(i<size)
        {
            Node n=(Node)nodes.get(i);
            n.visited=false;
            i++;
        }
    }

    //Utility methods for printing the node's label
    private void printNode(Node rootNode2)
    {
        System.out.print(rootNode2.label+" ---> ");
    }





}
```

Comment: Should we ignore the commented lines?

Comment: I'm going to debug this right now. Firstly, I found two unclosed literals in the 'lets create nodes' bit of Main. You might want to fix those first if you copy-pasted that code to StackOverflow. It also found two calls to `g.connectNode` with three arguments instead of two.

Comment: Jesus man/woman, you could have done a tad bit of work and at least showed where the error was hitting.

Comment: Yes ignore anything commented

Comment: the commented out section in my main under addnode is where I wanted to get the user input

Comment: Can you also include the error stack trace?

Comment: At least show us the stack trace... If you want help, you've got to at least indicate where the problem is (especially if you're asking people to dig through ten pages of code to find it...).

Comment: In the code you've posted, the `Graph` object `g` is never instantiated. I added `Graph g = new Graph();` and it gave the following output: `Houston ---> Seattle ---> Vancouver ---> Portland ---> Boise  ---> Denver  ---> Boston ---> Jacksonville ---> Baltimore ---> Oakland  ---> Olympia ---> Detroit ---> Omaha ---> Chicago ---> Memphis ---> Louisville ---> Nashville`, with no errors.

Comment: Your code is working fine....its giving the above mentioned output by Philippe (http://pastebin.com/RKr6X4fC)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that in `Graph.getUnvisitedChildNode`, you search through the `nodes` array with `nodes.indexOf(n)`. This is done on the first element of your queue first, which is the root node, and this is all good.

However, the root node is set to `new Node(shortPath)` in `Main` (line 130, see edit). This new node is never added to the array. Java doesn't look what the label inside this node might be, but currently looks only if it's the same instance of `Node`.

You could try to fix this by adding the following method to the `Node` class:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if(o == null) return false;
    if(!(o instanceof Node)) return false;
    return label.equals(((Node)o).label);
}
```

This method will say that two nodes are equal if their labels are equal. This would fix your tree, I hope. I'll try this right now, while you try to interpret what my code actually does.

EDIT: You modified the code here, it's now commented out and on a different line.

EDIT2: Adding the override of the `equals` method seems to work, for me.

Comment: @Ghostkeeper You saved me! Thank you so much! I turned it in just in the nik of time!